# CSS class for an HTML Table is affecting another Class Table Layout

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am pretty new to figuring out the quirks of css. I will admit, I am a novice.

I have the following HTML:
Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a0mfzc1v/1/) for JSFiddle

```
<table class="mainInfo4Col">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>        
</tr>    
</table>        
<table class="tableinfo">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>        
  </tr>    
</table>

<style>
table {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size:8pt;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-color: #0b23b5;
    color: #06187F;
    border-top-width : 1px;
            border-right-width : 1px;
            border-bottom-width : 1px;
            border-left-width : 1px;
            border-color: #010173;
            border-style : solid solid solid solid;
            width:100%;
        }
        th {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
            font-size:8pt;
            color: #06187F;
            text-transform : uppercase;
        }
        td {
            padding: 1px;
        }
        table.mainInfo4Col {
            border-spacing: 1px 1px;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 1px 1px;
        }
        .mainInfo4Col tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #F2F1F1;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
            font-size: 8pt;
            color: #010173;
            height:20pt;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 1px 1px;
        }
        .mainInfo4Col tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #DAE1E8;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
            font-size: 8pt;
            color: #010173;
            height:20pt;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 1px 1px;
        }
        table.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3) {
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: right;
            white-space:nowrap;
            width: 25%;
        }
        table.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(4) {
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: left;
            white-space:nowrap;
            width: 25%;
        }
        table.tableinfo {
            border-spacing: 3px 3px;
            table-layout: inherit;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table.tableinfo th, td {
           padding: 1px;
        }
        table.tableinfo table:not(tr:first-child) {
           border-collapse: collapse;
           border-spacing: 1px 1px;
           vertical-align: top;
         }
     </style>
```

*EDIT added CSS STYLE.

My css is defined for a normal non class table, .mainInfo4Col Table, .tableinfo Table. However, it seems like the way I have written my CSS definitions, .mainInfo4Col class is affecting the appearance of .tableinfo.

For example, .mainInfo4Col should be the only table with defined text alignment. But, the other table class once rendered has similar behavior.

I have tried defining my css with table.class, or .class table with no difference. I too have tried defining using different selectors.

I thought maybe I should use ">", for it to only take in parent-child relations but no success. .

Any tips, are appreciated. 
The end goal is to have  .mainInfo4Col class to have different odd and even row colors, and have even and odd tds be defined with their own characteristics.

While, .tableinfo, should have it's own definitions. Sadly, .mainInfo4Col conflicts with the text alignment for .tableinfo class. Thank you.

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. Don't make jsFiddle the sole source of it.

Comment: Try putting spaces between table and your class definitions. So: `table .mainInfo4col { style here; }`

Comment: @ j08691       Added the css, so my post isn't reliant on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some rulesets like this:

```
table.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3) {
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: right;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 25%;
}
```

I suspect that you need them to be this:

```
table.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(1), 
table.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(3) {
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: right;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 25%;
}
```

This

```
td:nth-child(3) {
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: right;
        white-space:nowrap;
        width: 25%;
    }
```

is affecting all `td` that are 3rd child **in any table**

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1euLku0r/)

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. It has been fixed. Thank you for the help.  I just thought one table.mainInfo4Col would affect both selectors. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to style on elements tags (  etc). For things that effect things visualy, ie the presentation layer, colors, fonts...stick with classes. You can add multiple classes to your elements, like class="block-style element-style modifier-style".

```
    .mainInfo4Col {
    border-top-width : 1px;
    border-right-width : 1px;
    border-bottom-width : 1px;
    border-left-width : 1px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #010173;
    border-style : solid solid solid solid;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border-spacing: 1px 1px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}


.mainInfo4Col  tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: #F2F1F1;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
        color: #010173;
        height:20pt;
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        border-spacing: 1px 1px;    
}

.mainInfo4Col tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: #DAE1E8;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
        color: #010173;
        height:20pt;    
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        border-spacing: 1px 1px;  
}


.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3) {   
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: right;
        white-space:nowrap;
        width: 25%;
}

.mainInfo4Col td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(4) {                 padding: 1px;    
        text-align: left;
        white-space:nowrap;
        width: 25%; 
}

.tableinfo {
    border-top-width : 1px;border-right-width : 1px;
    border-bottom-width : 1px;
    border-left-width : 1px;
    border-color: #010173;
    border-style : solid solid solid solid;
    width:100%;
    }

.tableinfo th, td { padding: 1px; }

.tableinfo:not(tr:first-child) { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 1px 1px;  vertical-align: top;}
```